# Create custom web service in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010

I need to create a new web service and call it through javascript (jQuery).
Any help will be appreciated.

Sandra

Answer (score 5):

I had to do this recently.  I found this article very helpful:  http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html

There's quite a few steps to take, so I won't list them all here.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I managed to implement the WCF service and tested it through code which works fine. But when I try it with jQuery it returns error statues=500. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Check the developer dashboard/trace log and ULS log for any exception details.

Comment: The correct URL seems to be http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html